# I have repeated JS code, how do I turns these into functions

Tags: javascript, function, loops, if-statement

Here is the JSFiddle link for my project, you can see the full app.js here... https://jsfiddle.net/be4pLh7s/1/

Basically I am trying to build a contact diary where you can create new contacts and then be able to edit or delete them at a later stage...

on line 85 onwards is the click event for the Edit and Delete buttons, I THINK that the way I have written this part of the code maybe incorrect because I have repeated loops and if statements.

I have tried putting these repeated parts of the code into functions but then the app crashes and I receive different errors. I have tried a couple of things to overcome these errors but still cant get it to work and or get my head around this.

Please could you advise if the code is correct... have I repeated myself? If I have then please can you show/tell me how to make this code better in terms of DRY, and readability. Thank you.

How do I code separate functions for the "Edit", "Save" and "Delete" buttons.

This line of code is repeated 3 times  -

```
for (var i = 0; i < contactsBook.length; i++) {
            if (contactsBook[i].firstName === ul.getAttribute('data-person')) {}
```

This line of code is repeated 2 times -

```
const ulChild = ul.childNodes;
          for (var j = 0; j < ulChild.length; j++) {
            if (ulChild[j].tagName === "LI") {}
```

Here is the part of the code in question -

```
//Click event for Edit and Delete buttons.
contacts.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

  if (e.target.tagName === "BUTTON") {
    const button = e.target;
    const ul = button.parentNode;
    if (button.textContent === "Edit") {
      for (var i = 0; i < contactsBook.length; i++) {
        if (contactsBook[i].firstName === ul.getAttribute('data-person')) {
          const ulChild = ul.childNodes;
          for (var j = 0; j < ulChild.length; j++) {
            if (ulChild[j].tagName === "LI") {
              const items = ulChild[j];
              const input = document.createElement('input');
              input.type = 'text';
              input.value = items.textContent;
              items.textContent = "";
              items.insertBefore(input, ulChild.childNodes);
              button.textContent = 'Save';
            };
          };
        };
      };
    } else if (button.textContent === "Save") {
      for (var i = 0; i < contactsBook.length; i++) {
        if (contactsBook[i].firstName === ul.getAttribute('data-person')) {
          const ulChild = ul.childNodes;
          for (var j = 0; j < ulChild.length; j++) {
            if (ulChild[j].tagName === "LI") {
              console.log(ulChild[j]);
            };
          };
        };
      };
    } else if (button.textContent === "Delete") {
      contacts.removeChild(ul);
      for (var i = 0; i < contactsBook.length; i++) {
        if (contactsBook[i].firstName === ul.getAttribute('data-person')) {
          contactsBook.splice(i,1);
          localStorage.setItem('addbook', JSON.stringify(contactsBook));
        };
      };
    };
  };
});
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't see that much repeated code... What exactly are you trying to move?

Comment: the loops and the if statements -

    if (button.textContent === "Edit") {
      for (var i = 0; i < contactsBook.length; i++) {
        if (contactsBook[i].firstName === ul.getAttribute('data-person')) {
          const ulChild = ul.childNodes;
          for (var j = 0; j < ulChild.length; j++) {
            if (ulChild[j].tagName === "LI")

Comment: Well the Delete part only has one for loop, doesn't go through the childs.

Comment: @Darsh2987: Then you'd need to mode the loops to a function, and pass some kind of callback. I doubt your code would get more readable.

Comment: Seems like https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is more appropriate for this type of question. Anyway, here's two I think most critical aspects: 1. DO NOT store your data in HTML and DO NOT use HTML as your primary data source when you need to find something 2. Separate different logical blocks (Save, Edit, Delete, Find-Contact-By-Name) and move them to separate function. Try to not rely on any global variables, only on arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Not much of repeated code. Only hint I could give is if you want to use more javascrpt flare, e.g. .forEach instead of standard for loop and .filter since you have a for and if statement.

For an example

```
for (var i = 0; i < contactsBook.length; i++) {
        if (contactsBook[i].firstName === ul.getAttribute('data-person'))
....
```

Can be done with:

```
contactsBook.filter(book => book.firstName === ul.getAttribute('data-person'))
```

Not that it makes any difference.